# jQuery .scrollTop(); + animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I set the page to scroll to top when a button is clicked.  But first I used an if statement to see if the top of the page was not set to 0.  Then if it's not 0 I animate the page to scroll to the top.

```
var body = $("body");
var top = body.scrollTop() // Get position of the body

if(top!=0)
{
  body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500');
}
```

The tricky part now is animating something AFTER the page has scrolled to the top.  So my next thought is, find out what the page position is. So I used console log to find out.

```
console.log(top);  // the result was 365
```

This gave me a result of 365, I'm guessing that is the position number I was at just before scrolling to the top.

My question is how do I set the position to be 0, so that I can add another animation that runs once the page is at 0?

Thanks!

Comment: it is needed that those button on which you fire event always visible? If not then i have a code which not need any kind of condition which can be do easy for your first condition

Comment: There should not be quotes around the milliseconds. The "string" the documentation refers to are the slow/fast

Answer (score 340, accepted):

To do this, you can set a callback function for the animate command which will execute after the scroll animation has finished.

For example:

```
var body = $("html, body");
body.stop().animate({scrollTop:0}, 500, 'swing', function() { 
   alert("Finished animating");
});
```

Where that alert code is, you can execute more javascript to add in further animation.

Also, the 'swing' is there to set the easing. Check out http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's what I needed. I also added a delay since the class is added so quickly.

if(top!=0)
   {
    console.log("hidden scroll");
    body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing', function() { 
    console.log("Finished animating");
    leftitems.delay(1000).removeClass("slide"); 
    });
}

Comment: I had to mention animate duration without quotes when I had only 2 parameters for animate function. That was weird.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because this post is 4 years old, but I think in newer versions of jQuery you need to remove those single quotes around the timing: body.animate({scrollTop:0}, 500, 'swing', function() { 
   alert("Finished animating");
});

Comment: Your callback will execute twice, by the way, because you selected two elements.

Comment: Thomas had good point adding body and html. Case 1. Chrome reading body and srolling, FIrefox need html to do it.

Comment: Just tried – $('html') does not work in Chrome and $('body') does not work in Firefox, so $('html, body') is needed. And also calling .stop() is a good thing – I tried to call animate several times quickly in chrome and after that I could not scroll down the page.

Comment: @ThomasStiegler You same my day

Answer (score 68):

Try this code:

```
$('.Classname').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `$("html")` should be used instead, because in your case if you add a callback function it will be called twice, once for *html* and once for *body*. And using *body* does nothing.

Comment: it seems that depends on the browser. in some, $('html') may do nothing, so you need to use both, and take care of the callback triggered twice.

Answer (score 39):

Use this:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

    var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 8):

for this you can use callback method

```
body.animate({
      scrollTop:0
    }, 500, 
    function(){} // callback method use this space how you like
);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this instead:

```
var body = $("body, html");
var top = body.scrollTop() // Get position of the body
if(top!=0)
{
       body.animate({scrollTop :0}, 500,function(){
         //DO SOMETHING AFTER SCROLL ANIMATION COMPLETED
          alert('Hello');
      });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Simple solution:

scrolling to any element by ID or NAME:

```
SmoothScrollTo("#elementId", 1000);
```

code:

```
function SmoothScrollTo(id_or_Name, timelength){
    var timelength = timelength || 1000;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id_or_Name).offset().top-70
    }, timelength, function(){
        window.location.hash = id_or_Name;
    });
}
```

Comment: '**timelength**' is already passed-in as a parameter so no need to declare it with 'var'. An 'edit' of this answer was not possible, as it was less than 6 characters! ;-) +1

Comment: @AnthonyWalsh no way afaik. `var` is needed not to overwrite the global one (if there exist global variable with that name)

Comment: Fair enough ;-) I am using _TypeScript_ and passing in a number directly as a parameter for _timelength_ so all local scope in my case. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Code with click function()

```
    var body = $('html, body');

    $('.toTop').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        body.animate({scrollTop:0}, 500, 'swing');

});
```

`.toTop` = class of clicked element maybe `img` or `a`

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery("html,body").animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#your-elemm-id-where you want to scroll").offset().top-<some-number>}, 500, 'swing', function() { 
       alert("Finished animating");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use both CSS class or HTML id, for keeping it symmetric I always use CSS class for example

```
<a class="btn btn-full js--scroll-to-plans" href="#">I’m hungry</a> 
|
|
|
<section class="section-plans js--section-plans clearfix">
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js--scroll-to-plans').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.js--section-plans').offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***you must see this***

```
$(function () {
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

or try them

```
$(function () {$('a').click(function () {
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 600);
return false;});});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").stop().animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        console.log(confirm('Like This'))
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I was facing a similar issue and this worked fine for me:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'element', function() {
  let posTop = jQuery(target).offset().top;
  console.log(posTop);
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: posTop}, 1, function() {
    posTop = jQuery(target).offset().top;

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: posTop}, 'slow');
  });
});
```