# Making window.scrollTo() physically scroll to a certain point

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the `window.scrollTo();` method on a button click. But, when I click the button, it just jumps to the position. I want it to physically display the scrolling to the position of the window. How can I do this?

Comment: Execute `.scrollTo` 60 times per second and calculate the location it should be at at time `t`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 not sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: Create a linear function where the horizontal axis is t (time) and the vertical axis is y (scrollTop). Repeatedly change the scrollTop to the corresponding y value with the time until it reaches the expected scrollTop. There's a bit math involved, and if you even want to add in [easing with cosine/sine](http://easings.net/en) it would be much messier. If you prefer jQuery, here's an example with all those math handled by jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ewpx30av/

Comment: (Duplicate) Take a look at this response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475198/jquery-scrolltop-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery is the best answer for this. It makes it really simple

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".the_div_you_want_to_got_to").offset().top
 }, 1750);
```

If you have not used Jquery before, it is a javascript extension. You will need to include it in the head of your doc

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used jQuery before!