# css move elements smoothly

Tags: html, css

Trying to make userface more userfriendly i want to implement following:

I have a `table` with some `alert` above it. Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/McHUc/86/)

When I close alert table 'jumps' to the top. I want it to slide smoothly. I want to use `pure css`. I've read about `transition and animation` but i think that's not what i need, or maybe i am wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642748/bootstrap-content-smooth-slideup-when-closing-alert

Comment: Roope, thank you but i was looking for pure css solution, something like transition works, you know

Comment: Animations ARE what you need. Just animate alert height to zero (slide up) or scale it for a zoom out effect.

Answer (score -2):

K, so you can do it with pure css. Bootstrap removes the `in` class from the alert at the beginning of the fade out. We can use that to apply css to the alert before it's removed from the page.

```
.fade {
    max-height: 400px;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
        -ms-transition: .3s;
            transition: .3s;
}

.fade:not(.in) {
    max-height: 0;
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/McHUc/92/

Comment: Added vendor prefixes which are needed for broader browser support. So it wouldn't work on most browsers. Updated sample code and fiddle.