# Is it possible to animate Window.scrollTop

Tags: gwt, scroll

I would like to add animate smooth, any adia?

```
Window.scrollTo(0, MyPanel.getAbsoluteTop());
```

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475198/jquery-scrolltop-animation

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery animate function for the same.

```
$('html').animate({ scrollTop: '0' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using velocity.js and JSNI call:

```
public static native void setAnimatedScrollTop(MyView instance, String topElementId, String scrollPanelId, int offsetPosition) /*-{
    $wnd.Velocity($wnd.document.getElementById(topElementId), 'scroll',
      {duration: 1000, offset: offsetPosition, container: $wnd.document.getElementById(scrollPanelId),
            complete: function(){
                instance.@com.project.client.views.MyView::setScrollAnimationInProgress(Z)(false);
            }
    });
}-*/;
```