# How to animate window scroll in gwt

Tags: javascript, gwt

I want to animate window scroll in gwt . I saw the post on [Is it possible to animate Window.scrollTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727981/is-it-possible-to-animate-window-scrolltop) but its giving me $ undefined exception. Is there any way to do it in gwt.

Thanks

Comment: add the exception please.

Comment: If you're running it from JSNI code, remember to use `$wnd.$(...)`. If you're trying to run this from Java code, either move it to JSNI code or use GwtQuery.