# Jquery scrollTop does not work with $(Window).animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I know a similar question has been asked and answered here - [jQuery .scrollTop(); + animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475198/jquery-scrolltop-animation).

I was trying to understand why if I try this-

```
 $(window).animate({scrollTop:300},500)
```

The page does not scroll.

However, if I try the below one as suggested in an earlier SO question, it works fine -

```
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:300},500).
```

What's more confusing is, if I just try the following (without any animation), it works fine -

```
$(window).scrollTop(300);
```

Can someone please help to understand what I am getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Because the scrollTop property works with(scrolls) the elements inside the window(html, body etc.) and not the window itself.

Comment: It does not work, because `$(window)` does not have scrollTop property.

Comment: If I just type this in a console $(window).scrollTop(300) then it works