# scroll down on click with animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html page. And I want to scroll down on button click ( button has class  "s_down_button" ) with animation.

I need scroll screen on element_height + 20 pixels down.

element_height - height of element with "tp-bgimg"  class

So I try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".s_down_button").click(function(){
        var element_height = $(".tp-bgimg").height();
        var scroll_height = element_height +20;
        $('body').scrollTo(scroll_height);
    }); 

});
```

but I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollTo is not a function
```

Comment: Of course, `scrollTo` is not a jQuery method. See here how to do this properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475198/jquery-scrolltop-animation (finding that yourself should have been trivial btw., if you did some  basic research.)

Comment: there are countless jQuery plugins for that... and also countless questions here regarding this subject. bothered google?

Comment: Here you go, my [own gist](https://gist.github.com/yairEO/7030050) for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scroll_height }, 600);
```

where 600 is time of animation in miliseconds. For more info look at [animate jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: positionToScrollTo}, 500);
```

What I like to do is create a scrollTo function that calls this line of code:

```
function scrollTo(position) {
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: position}, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".s_down_button").click(function(){
        var element_height = $(".tp-bgimg").height();
        var scroll_height = element_height +20;
        $('body').animate({scrollTop: scroll_height }, 500);
    });
});
```

If your element is not on very top of the page you should add the offset:

```
var offsetOfElement = $(".tp-bgimg").offset().top;
```

So the variable scroll height is:

```
var scroll_height = element_height + offsetOfElement +20;
```