# Why in Chrome it's $("html") and in Safari $("body") works for the scroll effect? How could I make a perfect solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I found this is exactly what I want:
[jQuery .scrollTop(); + animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475198/jquery-scrolltop-animation)

```
var body = $("html, body");
body.stop().animate({scrollTop:0}, 500, 'swing', function() { 
  alert("Finished animating");
});
```

But the problem as a comment mentioned in the question is that the trigger function would fire twice.

I realize that it's because `$("html, body")` get two elements binding this event.

However, I noticed that I can't just simply remove one because in Safari it's `body` that works while in Chrome it's `html` that works.

And I don't know what would happen on other devices that I could access.

So, is there any perfect solution for this that I don't need to fire twice the function?

Comment: You could try debouncing the function

Comment: Wow, just did some Google of debouncing and my first time to hear that concept. Totally cool. Thanks!

Comment: Use [`document.scrollingElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scrollingElement) instead (polyfil: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/document.scrollingElement)