# Can i replace scrollTo() with animate() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrollto

```
if (proportionShown < 0.66 && recom.pageType == 'queryresult') {
  // scroll the container so its top hits the top of the window
  // If the screen height is smaller than the height of the smart
  // filter. otherwise, scroll so that the bottom of the filter
  // hits the top of the footer.
  if (dimensions.height > screen.height) {
    $.**scrollTo**(container, 700);
  } else {
    $.**scrollTo**({
      top: containerBottomYOffset - screen.height + $('#footer').height(),
      left : 0
    }, 700);
  }
}
```

Here, can i replace scrollTo with animate()? Since scrollTo() is deprecated in jQuery

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475198/jquery-scrolltop-animation

Comment: use `window.scrollTo(500, 0);` on Pure javascript or use `scrollTop` `scrollLeft`